# Angular 2 - Call other component function

Tags: javascript, angular

i'm trying to call another component function from a component. This is my constructor :

```
    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private appComponent: AppComponent
        ) {
        this.setUrl();
    }

    setUrl() {
        if (this.appComponent) {
            this.Url = this.appComponent.getEnvironnement();
        } else {
            setInterval(this.setUrl, 1000);
        }
    }
```

However, when I'm trying to property/function from my appComponent, I get an error saying : `appComponent is undefined`

Why my component is undefined, even if I initialize it on the beginning ?

Comment: Are you just trying to inject AppComponent into a child component? I don't know what you're aiming for but you probably don't want to do that, but do it with a "common service". Read up on dependency injection: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: Another great doc is https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction this is the 'Angular Way' to manage iteraction between components. Anyway, what @TomTom is right. Plus, you should't inject a component.

Comment: I've updated my code.

Comment: Or if you just want to pass data to a child component. You can use the @Input() attribute.

Comment: The link @ChristianBenseler is more suitable for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **@Output** for other component event binding.

Do use @**Input** and @**Output** instead of the inputs and outputs properties of the @Directive and @Component decorators

For more information you can visit following URl:
https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-2-components-inputs-outputs/

Comment: You call a method from another component by using import {Injector} from angular core package and use the get method from Injector. Sorry this isn't more comprehensive but it certainly is one of the best ways in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the non-app component is a child of the app component you could just flow data from the app component down to the child component.  Here we have the app component contain the environmentUrl logic.  This is then saved to as environmentUrl.  This is then passed down to the my-child component's url property.  Therefore no need to have the child component access the parent component's function, instead we can just flow the data down from the parent to the child.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <my-child [url]="environmentUrl"></my-child>
  `
})
export class App {
  environmentUrl: string;

  constructor() {
    this.environmentUrl = getEnvironment();
  }

  getEnvironment() {
    return '/some/url';
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{url}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() url: string;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Another advantage of this approach is that the ChildComponent is more reusable.  The ChildComponent doesn't know anything about the parent's method and can be used without explicitedly relying on the parent component.